# Dragging and scrolling (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay guys, I have been scratching my head like mad over this issue and have spent a good few hours trying to research how it works but I am yet to find an answer.

Basically the issue I am having is that I have a treeview of folders in my application i.e:

```
Catalog

  Brands
    Nike
    Adidas
    Lactose


  Styles
    Sandles
    Trainers
    Boots
```

The issue that I am trying to fix is that when I drag a folder around(This is handled in my DragDropManager class), I am unable to scroll up or down(simply displays a lovely stop sign).

This is a problem if I want to move something from the very top to the very bottom.

The scrolling works fine on its own without the dragging being done.

If anyone wishes to see any part of my code feel free to ask as I am unsure what to actually show you guys.

I have read through a good few articles and am just left scratching my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better approaches but what I have done is:

- During Dragging over your target element (QueryContinueDrag) you check if the control you are over has a scrollviewer in its visual tree.
- now check if you are near the edge of the scrollviewer, e.g. 10px away.
- scroll the scrollviewer

Here's some code:

Find associated ScrollViewer:

```
var _scrollViewerControl = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(treeView);

private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
where childItem : DependencyObject
{
  for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
  {
    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
    if (child != null && child is childItem)
      return (childItem)child;
    else
    {
      childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
      if (childOfChild != null)
        return childOfChild;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

In QueryContinueDrag determine current Position and delta to scrollviewer:

```
// as we don't have eventargs here exposing the current mouse position we use the
// win32 API to get the current mouse position
Win32.POINT p;
if (!Win32.GetCursorPos(out p))
{
    return;
}

//this is the point on the screen
Point point = new Point(p.X, p.Y);

//get position relative to scrollViewerControl
Point controlPoint = _scrollViewerControl.PointFromScreen(point);

if (controlPoint.Y < 10 && -10 < controlPoint.Y)
{
    _scrollViewerControl.LineUp();
}
else if (controlPoint.Y > _scrollViewerControl.ViewportHeight - 10 && _scrollViewerControl.ViewportHeight + 10 > controlPoint.Y)
{
    _scrollViewerControl.LineDown();
}

if (controlPoint.X < 10 && -10 < controlPoint.X)
{
    _scrollViewerControl.LineLeft();
}
else if (controlPoint.X > _scrollViewerControl.ViewportWidth - 10 && _scrollViewerControl.ViewportWidth + 10 > controlPoint.X)
{
    _scrollViewerControl.LineRight();
}
```

Comment: As stupid as this sounds, how would I implement this? Would I want to do it within the DragDropManager classes?

Comment: I don't know how your DragDropManager class implementation looks like, but what I have done is implement it there. I guess that you already have some event hooks in there and that you know the details of the drag/drop operation. E.g. who started the drag operation.

Best you show a small sample of your implementation in your question so we can get a better insight?

Comment: Well the thing is with your previous answer, I don't actually have a clue where the scrollviewer is as I am pretty sure the TreeView template has one already built into it, because as far as I can see there is nothing actually initilizing the scollbar

Comment: Yes thats true, the scrollviewer is part of the Treeviews ControlTemplate. Thats why you need the FindVisualChild method. If you are dragging over a control that has a scrollviewer, e.g. treeview you call the FindVisualChild(TreeView treeViewControlYouareCurrentlyOver), then you can use the second code snippet and determine the distances between your current point and the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I understand now. I hadn't come across VisualChild stuff before, thanks again.